# Fill Hidden field not working

Tags: javascript, html

Following issue, I want the UTM Parameter be filled in a hidden filed. But does not work. Am not familiar with javascript but all other fields worked only the utm makes issues. Thats the URL with Parameter

myurl.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=google

```js
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
 
// Put the variable names into the hidden fields in the form.

document.getElementsByName("ck_field_utm_campaign").value = campaign;
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="" name="ck_field_utm_campaign" class="ck_field_utm_campaign" id="ck_field_utm_campaign">
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array. (ElementS by tag name)

So when you write:

`document.getElementsByName("ck_field_utm_campaign").value = campaign;`

you're basically assigning the `.value` property to an array that is returned by the function. Instead use `.querySelector` (which returns a single element or null) or access the first item in the array returned by getElementsByName, and assign `.value` to it.

Using querySelector:

```
document.querySelector("[name='ck_field_utm_campaign']").value = campaign;
```

Accessing the first item:

```
var input = document.getElementsByName("ck_field_utm_campaign");
// input now contains an ARRAY of elements that match that name
// but if you're sure that only one input has that name you can easily access
// that input
input = input[0];
input.value = campaign;
```

Comment: And worth mentioning, `input.value` is not the same as `<input value="">`, which can cause a lot of headache if not careful.